# Select the type of triangle based on the input

Tags: java, beginner

I am trying to see if there is a way to improve my code this program ask for 3 number and calculate the what type of triangle it is

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Triangle{
    public static void main (String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 3 numbers that represent side of triangle (one by one): ");

        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        int num3 = scan.nextInt();


        boolean isoscelesTriangle = num1==num2 && num2!=num3 || num1!=num2 && num3==num1 || num3==num2 && num3!=num1;
        boolean equilateralTriangle = (num1 == num2 && num2 == num3) && num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0;
        boolean rightAngleTriangle = num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && ((num1 * num1) + (num2 * num2) == (num3 * num3) || (num1 * num1) + (num3 * num3) == (num2 * num2) || (num3 * num3) + (num2 *num2) == (num1 * num1));
        boolean commonTriangle = num1 + num2 > num3 || num1 + num3 > num2 || num2 + num3 > num1;
        boolean notTriangle = num1 > 0 && num2 > 0 && num3 > 0 && num1 >= (num2+num3) || num3 >= (num2+num1) || num2 >= (num1+num3);

        // calculate to check what triangle it is
         if(equilateralTriangle)
            System.out.println("The Numbers: " +num1+", " + num2 + " and " +num3+ " represent an equilateral triangle");

         else if (isoscelesTriangle)
             System.out.println("The Numbers: " +num1+", " + num2 +" and " +num3+ " represent an Isosceles Triangle");


        else if (rightAngleTriangle)
            System.out.println("The Numbers: " +num1+", " + num2 + " and " +num3+ " represent an right-angle Triangle");

         else if(commonTriangle)
             System.out.println("The Numbers: " + num1 + ", " + num2 + " and " + num3 + " represent an Common Triangle");


         else if (notTriangle)
             System.out.println("The Numbers: " +num1+", " + num2 + " and " +num3+ " cannot represent an triangle");

    }
}
```

this is the code that I did. I can't change the order of the calculation but I wonder if there is way to make it shorter and better. or maybe improve the calculation.

*I am new to programing in general so if you have any tips to help me in general its will be good

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[DRY](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)
applies to this both in small and larger ways.

We several times see the expression

```
"The Numbers: " + num1 + ", " + num2 + " and " + num3 + " represent" ...
```

That's the trivial aspect.
Assign to a prefix string and you're done.

The five booleans are the more interesting aspect,
which we will come to.

---

```
        int num1 = scan.nextInt();
        int num2 = scan.nextInt();
        int num3 = scan.nextInt();
```

There's nothing *wrong* with that.
Certainly they are all numbers.
But think about what you'll be using them for.
In some ways they're not as convenient as they could be.

Every text since
[Euclid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_Elements)
has used alpha, beta, ... ok some have used a, b, c.
Let's go with that when defining three `int`s.

In many languages, including [java](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaBeans#JavaBean_conventions), it is [conventional](https://geosoft.no/javastyle.html#General)
for booleans and predicates to [start with](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#isPresent()) `is`.
(Or "has" / "have" for plural.)
I will follow that here.

Also, we should report fatal error immediately upon
noticing any negative numbers.
It is reasonable for the rest of the code to be
able to safely assume it is working with non-negative
lengths.

Finally, to simplify matters, I am going to enforce
monotonicity. The user is free to enter figures in any order,
but by the time we've validated them we will have
`a <= b && b <= c`.
In some languages we might rely on `sorted()`;
here we can ask `ArrayList` to `.sort()`.

---

Ok, time for some math.

It seems like you'd want to establish this one first,
as absent the triangle inequality the others just don't make sense.
I choose to define these in the positive,
as humans do a better job reasoning in that way.
It avoids the infamous double negative.

```
        boolean isValid = a >= 0 && b >= 0 && c >= 0;
        boolean isTriangle = c <= a + b;
```

We should bail immediately if `! isValid` or `! isTriangle`.
Note that `isTriangle` still admits of
degenerate triangles, such as `2, 3, 5`.
Feel free to define `isDegenerate` if you like.

Now `isEquilateralTriangle = a == b && b == c`,
just as you defined.
We can quibble about whether the first term is needed,
but following your code we have
`isIsoscelesTriangle = !isEquilateralTriangle && (b == a || b == c)`.
Notice how sorting makes the middle entry, `b`,
the one of interest.

Here's the original motivation for sorting:
`isRightAngleTriangle = a*a + b*b == c*c`.
We're dealing with
[Pythagorean triples](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple)
here, given the `int` declaration.
I caution you that, if floats and round-off were involved,
you'd want to compare `abs()` difference
to a small epsilon, or use a fancier measure like
[relative error](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Approximation_error).

Having dispatched some specific types, we *could*
define `isCommonTriangle = !isIsoscelesTriangle && !isEquilateralTriangle && !isRightTriangle`.
But for this code it's probably better to just
leave it as the default case when reporting an outcome.
That is, simply use an `else`.

---

There is an opportunity to pass sorted `a, b, c`
to a helper function here.
But "extract helper" might be a topic
for your next coding assignment.

---

Summary:

There are many ways to code up the several details of an assignment.
Look for what is common across them,
find their hierarchy,
and tackle them in sequence.
It simplifies both your code,
and reasoning about your code,
if you discard the pathological cases early on.

Comment: @mdfst13, thank you. Fixed. (And yeah, I don't take a position on the whole degenerate thing, not sure what the professor's perspective was. It _does_ seem pretty clear that we should not admit negative lengths.)

Comment: I would also suggest extracting the categorization of the triangle to a separate method, returning the category.

Comment: *In many languages, including java, it is conventional for booleans and predicates to start with is.* - I know this is not wikipedia, but citation needed. That is a convention on boolean *getters* but not boolean *variables*. Your IDE knows which type of variable it is, prefixing all boolean variables with "is" seems like Hungarian notation to me.

Comment: As far as I know, it is absolutely not a convention to prefix booleans with "is". While I leave the burtden of proof to the original claimant, I can provide an example of boolean variables representing a plural: "isMultipleResultsFound". That cannot make sense, we would have to introduce the "are" prefix now and then the slope was already greased. :)

Comment: I see you added some sources for your naming convention claim, great, however do note that `Optional.isPresent` is a *method* and not a *variable*. Java beans says that the *accessor method* should be prefixed with "is", how would you name the accessor method if your property is already prefixed with "is"? `boolean isIsValid()` doesn't look great to me. As for geosoft.no, [I don't see how that's an authority on the subject in any way](https://geosoft.no/html/about.html).

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear that the sides must be *integers* - in real life, triangles exist with fractional-length sides, so I'd expect to see us dealing with positive floating-point numbers.

Consider accepting the lengths from the `args` that we're currently ignoring.  That will make your program easier to use.

The logic can be simplified if we *sort* the three lengths before classifying the triangle.  Then the test for equilaterality becomes simply `side[0] == side[2]`, for example, and for right-angle is a single equality test, rather than ORing together three different ones.

Comment: SORTING, YES! When I read the question "sort them" was the first suggestion that popped into my mind. Makes the whole thing so much easier.